# Udemy and Upwork has built on which technology? (technology used for website and for native app (Android & iOS))

Tags: javascript, android, ios, angularjs, progressive-web-apps

I have a requirement to build an app which will be the combination of **Udemy** and **Upwork**. The app should work as a website and as a native app.

1. I m concern about which technology should i use for FrontEnd?
2. Instead of using 3 technologies (for 1.Website 2.Android 3.iOS). I want to precise my development.

as I am the user of Udemy, I have experienced some differences in design in website and in android app, so my questions is **Has the Udemy app built in different technologies for website and for native app?**

I need some suggestions which technology should i use to build app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

React and React Native could be good options if you like to keep the development process similar through web- and app development. My second recommendation would be to use Apache Cordova/Adobe Phonegap.

Maybe [BuiltWith](https://builtwith.com/) could be a useful tool to check what technology is used to build a specific website.

Comment: Thanks @daan ,I really appreciate your quick suggestion. I have gone through the **BuiltWith**  [link](https://builtwith.com/detailed/udemy.com) to check the technology, Seems Udemy is in React also used some part of Angular.  as I have good experience in Ionic Frame which is Cordova / [link](https://capacitor.ionicframework.com/), and Angular so i think i should go for Ionic. I have less experience in React, I m concern about Videos and Live stream now, please suggest if you know any cordova plugins for Videos